# sudo unknown group - Need help getting NextCloud setup with external HD

Tags: docker, nextcloud

I installed nextcloud on a raspberry via docker.  I've had it running fine.  Now I'm trying to get it to use an external USB HD.  I mounted the HD to /media/exhd.
I'm following this tutorial, this command is giving me an error that I don't understand:
https://ownyourbits.com/2017/06/08/nextcloudpi-docker-for-raspberry-pi/

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /media/exhd -H fd://


sudo: unknown group: /media/exhd
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Please help me understand the error.  I don't understand what it's trying to do.  The dockers man page only shows a '-G' option.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed an interesting problem. Even the [dockerd reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) does **not** include a `-g` option on top, but refers to it [later on](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#miscellaneous-options), what seems kind of weird to me.

But as long as you are not typing commands by hand, I would always recommend to use the long option's name, because if you come back later, you will most likely understand the long options much better as the short ones:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --data-root /media/exhd --host fd://
```

You could also consider adding (or changing) the config file at `/etc/docker/daemon.json` - for me this is the best solution, because it can easily be backed up...

```json
{
  "data-root": "/media/exhd/data",
  "exec-root": "/media/exhd/exec"
}
```

`exec-root` contains the execution state files, that you might also want to store on your hdd (`--exec-root` if using the cmd option), to keep everything together...